# Laravel routes and blade templating with reactjs

Tags: php, laravel, routes, reactjs, laravel-blade

Is there some way I can use blade type syntax with React to handle my Laravel routes? Let's say I have something like the following:

```
<div class="card">
    <a href="{{ route('account.show', $user->slug) }}">Go to your account</a>
</div>
```

If I try to make this into a Reactjs component, clearly the blade type syntax won't work.

I *have* looked into React Router, but don't exactly know how it would fit into my application, or if it is even necessary for me to use (I'd much rather use plain Laravel routes).

Comment: RE react-router, it's primarily a client side router, so you only need it for single page apps. If hard page loads makes sense for what you're doing (e.g. a blog, but not an email client), then you don't need a client side router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React code is not executed by Laravel, but by the user's browser. So when the time comes to generate that href, inside the user's browser, the code does not have any more access to Laravel or Blade tools.

What you can do is to pass all the info you need to your React app, beforehand, when you use blade to generate the top level React invocation:

```
<script>
    React.render(
        MyApp({
            accountShow: "{{ route('account.show', $user->slug) }}",
            //etc.
        }),
        document.getElementById('myContainer')
    )
</script>
```

So then in your React app you can use those properties and pass them down to inner components, e.g:

```
<CardLink href={this.props.accountShow}>
    Go to your account
</CardLink>
```

Comment: This works, but is this scalable, or is there a better way to do it? It works fine now however, thanks!

Comment: Alternatively, you can install the [laroute](https://github.com/aaronlord/laroute) package. It will generate a `laroute.js` file that you can include in your page and use to generate routes like this from React: `laroute.route('hello.{planet}', {planet : 'world'})` Keep in mind that if you need some model values like `$user->slug` you will still have to pass them to Javascript, either as top-level props (as I showed) or as global Javascript constants (variables, really.)